# Single VSPackage with a context menu item and options page

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, vsix, vspackage

I am struggling to find out how to make two seperate controls in a single VSPackage. Currently I have two seperate projects (a context menu and an options page) that build into two seperate VSIX installers. I can't find a single example on how to make multiple menu items in one project or two projects building into one installer. How  and what is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Define what you mean by "two separate controls in a single VSPackage". There's no reason why you would need multiple packages here. You can readily implement any number of menu commands and options pages in just a single package, and deploy via a single .VSIX.

You should also indicate which version(s) of Visual Studio you are targeting, as the project and item templates in VS 2015 are substantially different that the earlier versions.

Comment: I would like an options page and menu controls that read from this options page. So far I have not yet found an example to implement multiple menu commands with an option(s) page. Just examples on singular options page or a menu command. How do create/register a VSPackage that creates a menu command and an option page. Do I complete this all in the package class? Further more, there really isn't ANY examples on how the VSIX framework works just "do this, add this annotation, create this class". My build is for VS 2013.

Comment: Update: I was able to get options and multiple menu commands in the same package. Thanks for the tip. A lot of the examples I found online were either for 2015 or simple "do this" tutorials, without context it is difficult to understand how the magic is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a VSIX dependency to another VSIX project using the .vsixmanifest file. The resulting installer will install both projects. See [How to: Add a Dependency to a VSIX Package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997168.aspx).